# Can someone try to make this a bit better so I can see my mistakes or to make it more efficient I'm a beginner in python

Tags: python-3.x

It's a quiz for covid-19, if you have any symptoms it first asks for your name, then asks if you have any symptoms like a cough or a headache. If you say no, it asks more questions and if you say yes it says you have covid-19. It's in the newest python

```
name = input("your name is ") 

bad = input("hi " + name +  " do you have a cough ")

if bad == "no":
    bad2 = input("hello " + name + " do you have a sore throat ")
    if bad2 == "no":
        bad3 = input("hi " + name + " do you have a headache ")
        if bad3 == "no":
            bad4 = input("hi " + name + " do you have any pain ")
            if bad4 == "no":
                bad5 = input("hi " + name + " do you fell tired ")
                if bad5 == "no":
                    print("hi " + name + " you don't have covid")

if bad == "yes" or bad2 == "yes" or bad3 == "yes" or bad4 == "yes" or bad5 == "yes":
    print("sorry " + name + " you have covid-19 ..... and here a ticket of 1,000")
```

Comment: @Allex Holley please clarify your question. What do you mean by "make this a bit better"? We need to know what exactly do you need so we can help you.

Comment: @AllexHolley what do you mean by "make this a bit better"?

Comment: Code quality can be improved by storing the questions you want to ask in an array and then looping through this array.

Comment: Please be aware there is a dedicated site on StackExchange for [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Exactly the same thing using a bit more tidy and readable approach.
"Readable code is maintainable code."

```
name = input("Your name: ")
# array containing questions
q = [
    f"Hi, {name} do you have a cough?  ",
    "Do you have a soar throat?  ",
    "Do you have a headache?  ",
    "Do you feel tired?  ",]
# user promt
for i in q:
    response = input(i)
    if response == "yes":
        print(f"-> Sorry {name}, you have covid-19 ....." + 
            "and here's a ticket of 1,000.")
        break
else: 
    print("-> You don't have Covid.")
```